# Same signals but to different buttons

Tags: pyqt, qpushbutton, qt-signals

I have 2 sets of 3 push buttons, each with a QDialogButtonBox() as follows:

- "Add" (AcceptRole)
- "Remove" (RejectRole)
- "Clear" (ResetRole)

Something like that:

```
self.set1_btns = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox()
self.set1_btns.addButton("Add", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.AcceptRole)
self.set1_btns.addButton("Remove", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.RejectRole)
self.set1_btns.addButton("Clear", QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ResetRole)
```

where their role is about the same, the only difference between them is that they will be adding/removing/clearing each of their own QListWidget that I have 'assigned' to them.

To simplify things, the sets are as follows:
(ListX - QListWidget, Add/Remove/Clear - QPushButton)

- Set1 : List1, Add1, Remove1, Clear1
- Set2 : List2, Add2, Remove2, Clear2

This is my code:

```
def connect_signals(self):
    # List1 functions - Add, Remove, Clear
    self.set1_btns.accepted.connect(self.add_objects)
    self.set1_btns.rejected.connect(self.remove_objects)
    self.set1_btns.clicked.connect(self.clear_objects)

    # List2 functions - Add, Remove, Clear
    self.set2_btns.accepted.connect(self.add_objects)
    self.set2_btns.rejected.connect(self.remove_objects)
    self.set2_btns.clicked.connect(self.clear_objects)

def add_objects(self):
    selections = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    for sel in selections:
        # I can only define it to add to list1
        self.list1.addItem(sel)

def remove_objects(self):
    for item in self.list1.selectedItems():
        self.list1.takeItem(self.list1.row(item))

def clear_objects(self):
    # self.list1_btns are the QDialogButtons
    role = self.list1_btns.buttonRole(button)
    if role == QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ResetRole:
        self.list1.clear()
```

My question here would be how can I tell my function to tell which button from which of the sets are being click unto?

For sanity sake, I thought it will be ideal to combine into 1 functions since they work about the same, instead of writing 2 separate functions where the only changes I made will be the QListWidget variable.

Answer (score 2):

You can pass the `QListWidget` objects as arguments to those methods as follows:

```
def connect_signals(self):
    # List1 functions - Add, Remove, Clear
    self.add1.accepted.connect(lambda: self.add_objects(self.list1))
    self.remove1.rejected.connect(lambda: self.remove_objects(self.list1))
    self.clear1.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clear_objects(self.list1))

    # List2 functions - Add, Remove, Clear
    self.add2.accepted.connect(lambda: self.add_objects(self.list2))
    self.remove2.rejected.connect(lambda: self.remove_objects(self.list2))
    self.clear2.clicked.connect(lambda: self.clear_objects(self.list2))

def add_objects(self, listWidget):
    selections = ['aaa', 'bbb', 'ccc']
    for sel in selections:
        # I can only define it to add to list1
        listWidget.addItem(sel)

def remove_objects(self, listWidget):
    for item in listWidget.selectedItems():
        listWidget.takeItem(listWidget.row(item))

def clear_objects(self, listWidget):
    # self.list1_btns are the QDialogButtons
    #role = self.list1_btns.buttonRole(button)
    #if role == QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.ResetRole:
    listWidget.clear()
```

Where `lambda` is an anonymous function, provided by Python; the signal is connected to this anonymous function which contains a call to your method passing the `list1` or `list2` as arguments. Then the list objects are used inside your methods accordingly.

As you are connecting the `clear` buttons to only `clear` method, I believe that there is no need to check in `clear_objects` the role of the button. If you do want to check the role, you can pass the `self.list1_btns` and `self.list2_btns` as a second argument to `clear_objects` method.

Comment: Please ignore my post.. It is actually working. Yes, initially I was connecting `clear` method to `clear` button

Comment: Just a quick question though, is it possible for the `add` buttons of the 2 set to instinctively know each other? Eg. if I add 'itemA' in list1, when I press the add button for set2, list2 should not be adding 'itemA' because it is already in list1

Comment: I just realized that this code will wipe out any new additions if I tried to add any new objects. Eg. If list already contains 3 objects, and I tried to add another new object, the objects in the list got wipe out and now the list will only contains this 'new' single object only possibly due to `.clicked.connect` used